# Going through names of a set of matrices in Python

Tags: python, matrix

Let's say you have N matrices named A_1,...A_N. Is there anyway to loop through these matrices using `for`? I mean, something like:

```
B={}
for i in range(1,N+1):
       B[i]=A_i
```

`A_str(i)` or `A_+str(i)` of course did not work.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: A dictionary that contains these matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `globals()` function to retreive the global namespace, that returns a dictionary of all variables (in global namespace) , and then use the variable name (`string`) as key to get the value from it.

Example -

```
>>> A_1 = [1]
>>> gbl = globals()
>>> gbl['A_1']
[1]
```

For your case -

```
B={}
gbl = globals()
for i in range(1,N+1):
       B[i]=gbl['A_' + str(i)]
```

---

Another solution is to use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) to get the value using string , but please note this is very dangerous, if you do not control the inputs to `eval` because eval executes the expression in the string and returns the result.

Example -

```
>>> A_1 = [1]
>>> eval('A_' + str(1))
[1]
```

Comment: Beautiful answer but can you provide more insight on eval function may be a link or so

Comment: Added the link to documentation of `eval()` function in the answer.

Comment: upakaaram!  @Anand S Kumar

Comment: is that a tamil word? :)

Comment: No malayalam So tamilha romba nalathu  nandri

Comment: oh ok, angane kashta pettu tamil onnum parayanda , eniku manasilavilla :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81494/discussion-between-vignesh-kalai-and-anand-s-kumar).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. Put all those matrices in a list when you make them

```
matrices = []
...
matrices.append(current_matrix)
```

and then iterate over that list

```
for i,matrix in enumerate(matrices):
    B[i] = matrix
```